# Type disapearing on script element

Tags: javascript, html

I have included script that lookes like that

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.domain.com/script.js?<?php echo rand(10000,99999)?>">`

**the result** obvious:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.domain.com/script.js?55872"></script>`

**the problem** happens when i refresh the page, the type attribute is disapearing and the result changes to

`<script src="//www.domain.com/script.js?82554"></script>`

the site is stored in [Incapsula](http://www.incapsula.com/), but I tried to disable all the features and its still the same. **edit: apparently when i tried to disable it, i didnt wait enought time and it didnt kicked in**

I thought it might be because of the doctype declaration -> `<!DOCTYPE html>` because HTML5 dont need the type declaration. if so, how can I force him to keep the type attribute?

I know that in HTML5 doctype, type attribute is useless, but a third-party company uses it in their selector and I have to keep it there.

Comment: What kind of software uses a `type` attribute of `script` in a selector, and what kind of selector? Do you mean CSS selectors?

Comment: They are using a jQuery selector to check if their script exists.. something like that `$("script[type*=javascript][src*=somefile]")` so if there is no type attribute, he is not recognizing their script

Comment: It would be much more robust if they had a check for a variable in the script than the document itself...Thats my standard 'is loaded' check. Just because the tag is there doesn't mean it's loaded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with [Incapsula](http://www.incapsula.com/)

[image]

`Minify static HTML` is removing `type` attribute when he is detecting HTML5 doctype

I just disabled it

Answer (score 1):

If that's really a problem, then put the following at just before the `<body/>`

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); // get the script tags
for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
   elms[i].setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); //set the type attribute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you using php to echo out a random number already just change it to

```
<script <?php echo 'type="text/javascript"'; ?>  src="//www.domain.com/script.js?<?php    echo rand(10000,99999)?>">
```